# CodeIgniter site with an API. Same codebase but different controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm trying to figure out a way to have a CodeIgniter powered site with a front-end and an api. The front-end part would be `http://example.com` and the API for it `http://api.example.com`.

However I'm having problems seperating the controllers. Because both sites share pretty much the same data except for the controllers I don't really want maintain two different applications. Right now I have set up the following:

```
backend
└─ server
   └─ application
      └─ controllers
         ├─ api <- For http://api.example.com
         └─ www <- For http://example.com

frontend
├─ .htaccess
└─ index.php <- Where http://example.com points to

api
├─ .htaccess
└─ index.php <- Where http://api.example.com points to
```

This kind of works, but I have to change a lot of the routing and the default `/class/function/id/` pattern seems to break. So I want CodeIgniter to treat `controllers/api` and `controllers/www` as if it would be the "root controller directory" or find a better solution for it entirely which would fit my needs:

- The URLs should be `http://example.com` and `http://api.example.com`
- `controllers/api/Foo.php` shouldn't be accessible from `http://example.com/foo` or `http://example.com/api/foo` and vice versa.
- `http://example.com/foo/bar` should call `Foo::bar()`. Natively without `(:any)/(:any)` in the route configuration would be a plus.
- Because of the way it's set up right now the default controllers need to be in the `controllers` folder, but all the other logic is in the subfolders. This feels wrong.

routes.php:

```
if(API) {
    $route['default_controller'] = 'apihome';
    $route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'api/$1/$2';
    $route['(:any)'] = 'api/$1';
    $route['foo/(:num)'] = 'api/foo/$1';
} else {
    $route['default_controller'] = 'wwwhome';
    $route['(:any)'] = 'api/$1';
}
```

The `API` constant is set to true in `/api/index.php` and to false in `/frontend/index.php`

Comment: Can you show what you set for your routes?

Comment: @mim. I mainly just experimented, but nothing felt flexible enough. Somewhat like [this](http://pastebin.com/EZLPT4mC).

Comment: how you are checking in routes.php request from api from you are checking API in routes.php?

Comment: @umefarooq Are you asking where `if(API) {` is defined? It's set to true in `/api/index.php` and to false in `/frontend/index.php`